# Extracting raw (non string) parameter values from terraform using terraform-config-inspect

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to generate json from terraform modules using terraform-config-inspect (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-config-inspect).

**Note:** Started with terraform-docs but then found what it uses underneath and it's terraform-config-inspect library.

The problem is that I want to go beyond what terraform-config-inspect provides out of box at the moment:

As an example, I want to get the name of **aws_ssm_parameter** resource.

For example, I have resource like this:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "service_security_group_id" {
  name      = "/${var.deployment}/shared/${var.service_name}/security_group_id"
  type      = "String"
  value     = aws_security_group.service.id
  overwrite = "true"
  tags      = var.tags
}
```

and I would like to extract the value of the **name** parameter but by default it does not output this parameter. I tried to hack the code by modifying resource schema and other parts but ended up in getting empty string instead of name value or error because it contains parts like **${var.deployment}**.

When I set it to plain string then my modified code returns what I expect

```
"aws_ssm_parameter.service_security_group_id": {
  "mode": "managed",
  "type": "aws_ssm_parameter",
  "name": "service_security_group_id",
  "value": "/test-env/shared/my-service/security_group_id",
  "provider": {
    "name": "aws"
  }
}
```

but in normal case it fails with the following error

```
 {
  "severity": "error",
  "summary": "Unsuitable value type",
  "detail": "Unsuitable value: value must be known",
  ...
 }
```

I know that I could build something totally custom for my specific use case but I hope there is something that could be re-used :)

**So the questions are:**

- Is it somehow possible to take the real raw value from terraform resource so I could get **"/${var.deployment}/shared/${var.service_name}/security_group_id"** in json output?
- Maybe some other tool out there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input Variables in Terraform are a [planning option](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/plan.html#planning-options) and so to resolve them fully requires creating a Terraform plan. If you *are* able to create a Terraform plan then you can find the resolved values in [the JSON serialization of the plan](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/json-format.html), using steps like the following:

- `terraform plan -out=tfplan` (optionally include `-var=...` and `-var-file=...` if you need to set particular values for those variables.
- `terraform show -json tfplan` to get a JSON representation of the plan.

Alternatively, if you've already applied the configuration you want to analyse then you can get similar information from the JSON representation of the latest state snapshot:

- `terraform show -json` to get a JSON representation of the latest state snapshot.

As you've seen, `terraform-config-inspect` is only for static analysis of the top-level declarations and so it contains no functionality for evaluating expressions.

In order to properly evaluate expressions here *without* creating a Terraform plan or reading from a Terraform state snapshot would require reimplementing the Terraform Core runtime, at least to some extent. However, for this *particular* expression (which only relies on input variable values) you could potentially use the HCL API directly with some hard-coded placeholder values for those variables in order to get *a* value for that argument, derived from whatever you happen to have set `var.deployment` and `var.service_name` to in the [`hcl.EvalContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2#EvalContext) you construct yourself.

Comment: However, TF plan or show does not work for me. The true case is that I don't want variables to be replaced by real values from TF state or plan -> I exactly want the opposite - get exactly what's written there in TF code without replacing anything at all. If I have "value = aws_security_group.service.id" I don't want to see real SG ID from some environment -> I want to get simple string "aws_security_group.service.id"

Comment: The original source code gets discarded as part of parsing so there's no data structure in memory that will give you that directly, but if you write code to find the relevant `hcl.Expression` you can call the `Range` method on it to find its source location, and then use [`Range.SliceBytes`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/hcl/v2#Range.SliceBytes) to take just that fragment from the original source code, which you'll have to retain in memory yourself. This is not something HCL is designed to support, so this is a workaround rather than a solution.

Comment: Will give it a try, thanks! At the moment I was able to get TF filename and line number where resource starts from resource "Pos" parameter (type: SourcePos)". Having that it was easy to read the file from that line till the end of the resource and parse the relevant data.